# How do I remove a single item from an Arraylist with a button (a tag) in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to remove an item from an Arraylist when I click on the button in the browser. I have figured out how to remove all items but need to remove one at a time too.

This is my code for the remove all elements and single element:

```
    if (request.getParameter("removeAll") != null) {
        request.getSession().removeAttribute("cart");
        response.sendRedirect("CheckoutServlet");
        return;
    }
    
    if (request.getParameter("remove") != null) {
        request.getSession().removeAttribute("test");
        response.sendRedirect("CheckoutServlet");
        return;
    }
```

This is my code for the button that removes all:

```
        <a href="?removeAll=true">Remove All</a>
```

This is my code for the button that removes sinle element:

```
        <a href="?remove=true">Remove</a>
```

Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to specify *WHAT* to remove. Either in the 'href' part (perhaps `"?remove=$productId"` for example), or if the URL you're on t hat has the `?remove=true` link is, say, `https://yourserver.com/product/big-bag-of-rice`, then you can look at the URL path. But, if it doesn't, your only option is to put the thing to remove within the href.

Comment: I’m removing an item from my cart. I’m using jsp and servlet for the project. I have a for loop to add the product into the cart but can’t figure out how to remove a line from the cart. There is no product code or name for any as they are generated randomly